# Getting user's answer (System dialog - Android)

Tags: android, dialog, system, launcher

I am a newbie on Android and I am creating a launcher. I want apps to be removed (uninstalled) so I have a list and I invoke system to uninstall it.

How can I know if the user pressed "Cancel" or "Ok" in the system dialog? 
(I know the system will unisntall the app if I press "Ok" or wont if I press "Cancel", I just need to know how to get the answer to remove or not the app of my list [ArrayList]).

If you cant know it, how can I do to remove an app from a list without knowing if the user is going to uninstall it or not?

```
public void uninstall (int position){
    Uri package1 = Uri.parse("package:"+apps_block.get(position).name.toString());
    Intent uninstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, package1);
    startActivity(uninstall);
    AppDetail toRemove = adapter_block.getItem(position);
    adapter_block.remove(toRemove);
}
```

With this code, the app is always removed from my list even I press "Cancel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the item from the list immediately after `startActivity()`. The user has not even *seen* the dialog yet by that point.

You could listen for [the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` system broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED), confirm that it was for your requested package, and remove the package from the list at that point. By doing this from your activity via `registerReceiver()`, you can find out fairly quickly and have easy access to your UI code to update the list.